# MySQL command not executing through PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, escaping, character

I have 2 scripts that are very similar (location.php and event.php).

location.php executes perfectly however event.php does not.

The SQL in event.php works fine when I run it directly from the database.

My question is why and how I can fix it, I thought it could be an escape character issue for MySQL >php for line 7 of event.php.

Alternatively is it an issue with using user-variables through the php interface?

I have included 'projectDatabase.php' in case there is some connection setup issue I have missed but other scripts using this connection have worked fine.

location.php:

```
1  <?php
2     require_once 'projectDatabase.php';
3
4     $dbinstance = new projectDatabase();
5
6     $query = "UPDATE items SET latitude = ((RAND() * (51.3805 - 51.3770)) + 51.3770), longitude = ((RAND() * (-2.3320 - -2.3240)) + -2.3240), update_ts = NOW()";
7
8     $dbinstance->db->query($query);
9
10 ?>
```

event.php:

```
1  <?php
2     require_once 'projectDatabase.php';
3
4     $dbinstance = new projectDatabase();
5
6     $query = "SELECT @now := NOW();
7     UPDATE catches c JOIN (SELECT item_id, MAX(update_ts) AS ts FROM items GROUP BY item_id) AS i ON c.item_id = i.item_id SET c.spawn_time = i.ts WHERE c.catch_time > @now - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;
8     UPDATE items SET latitude = ((RAND() * (51.3805 - 51.3770)) + 51.3770), longitude = ((RAND() * (-2.3320 - -2.3240)) + -2.3240), update_ts = @now;";
9
10
11    $dbinstance->db->query($query);
12
13  ?>
```

projectDatabase.php:

```
1  <?php
2  class projectDatabase {
3      private $dbHost     = 'localhost';
4      private $dbUsername = 'XXXXXXXXX';
5      private $dbPassword = 'XXXXXXXXX';
6      private $dbName     = 'XXXXXXXXX';
7     
8     function __construct(){
9       if(!isset($this->db)){
10              $link = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName);
11              if($link->connect_error){
12                  die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $link->connect_error);
13              }else{
14                  $this->db = $link;
15              }
16          }
17    }
18  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, there's no instance variable named `$db` in `projectDatabase` class. You need to create one `public` instance variable named `$db` in `projectDatabase` class like this:

```
class projectDatabase {
    public $db;
    private $dbHost = 'localhost';
    ...
}
```